# Is "boundability" an acceptable word?

Tags: vocabulary, lexicon

Is there a word in English for "the quality of being susceptible of being bounded"?

Is "boundability" an acceptable word for that purpose? (It does not seem to appear in either Webster, Oxford, or Cambridge dictionaries.)

Just to clarify, "boundedness" (the quality of being bounded) does not work in my (mathematical) context because I need to distinguish between "the quality of being bounded" and "the quality of **being susceptible of** being bounded", which is precisely the key point in the argument.

Comment: I think your question, which is quite technical, will fare better in the Mathematics Stack Exchange: https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I knew what it meant when I read the title, so I’d say it’s a valid word, regardless of whether it’s in a dictionary. We make new words all the time.

Comment: Yes, it's certainly acceptable for such a concept. Mathematicians use their own terms anyway without too much concern for dictionary sensibilities.

Comment: That is true (and to a certain extent reasonable), I just wanted to be sure that the construction is OK and not be using a word which sounds too bad to a native speaker. Thank you! I will be happy to accept any of the last two comments as an answer.